# Laravel - How to accomplish authentication by permission?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I read the documentation about authentication and i'm little bit confuse.

I want to create a trait that log in users by permission, the idea is to create method on any controller that belongs to any part of the application (Admin, Normal user, Customer service), and from that method send the right permission to the trait login method.

The problem that I encounter is: How do I authenticate user by permission? Assume that I have permissions table and that table connected via another table to Users table. (many to many).

Is that mean that I should create a Guard for any part of the application?

Is there any other way to accomplish that?

I do can query for permission and then use Auth::attempt in order to log in user, but it's two queries and I thing it's kind of waste.

thanks

Comment: Authentication and authorization in laravel are two different things. Permissions relate to authorization which requires a user to have already signed in (even if that sign in happened during the same request).

Comment: @apokryfos I understand that, But what If one of the managers wants to log in the control panel, how can I authenticate him ? I don't want him to perform an action and get denied, I want to block him in the log in level...

Comment: Why do you need to do that. You can allow them to log in via the Auth middleware and them block them via the "can" middleware. There's no reason to deny a valid login on the grounds that they can't access a specific part of the site

Answer (score 0):

If you break it down, Its quite simple.

You have different users, Each user have some role(s), And a role have permission.
The best part is user types, Each user type can have role(s).
Now simply what you have to do is that, Redirect the user checking the user type to its related route.

The best place to redirect users after login is `AuthenticatesUsers` class :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, My question was how do I authenticate user by permission not how do I redirect users...

Comment: If i understand you, You cannot do what you are thinking, As i mentioned the class name above `AuthenticatesUsers` , That `authenticated` function is the first thing it calls after the auth, So thats your place, Give it a brief try.

Comment: For the auth mechanism, A every user is equal, The conditions will come after the login.